# How to make Magento 2 accessible using different url Domain without creating Multi Website?

Tags: magento2, url, base-url, multi-website

So using other PHP frameworks such as Laravel and CI, I can point my virtual host to the same project folder and access it with a different domain. However using Magento 2 the base URL is defined in the database and to access it with multiple domains we need to create multiple websites, I just need to access it from multiple domains without creating multiple website, how to do this?

For example:

I can access the same Magento 2 site using:

```
1. my.gov
2. mine.gov
```

if I go to another page:

```
1. my.gov/customer/account
2. mine.gov/customer/account
```

it won't change the base URL (without redirecting it)

Comment: This could not be archived on magento

Comment: @TuyenNguyen why?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen you are right.

Comment: Do you want to switch back and forth? And do you want to use this in production? I don't know if that is a good idea. But maybe you could try to set the base url on the fly? But I don't know if this will work since allot will be cached.

Comment: I want to use this in prod, and both the URL can access at the same time